# Next.js Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call'), try/catch won't work onClick?

Tags: javascript, next.js

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");
import React from "react";

export async function mySqlQuery(myQuery) {
  try {
    console.log("Running query...");

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    });

    connection.connect();

    connection.query(myQuery, function (error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      const output = results[0].solution;
      console.log(output);
    });

    connection.end();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message); // or "throw Error(e.message)", this shows it directly on top of the webpage
  }
}
```

The button i use to call the function (without the `() =>` Next.js thinks it's an object)

```html
<button onClick={() => mySqlQuery("SELECT 1 + 190 / 2 AS solution;")}> SQL PUSH </button>
```

I tried this too

```html
<button onClick={async () => await mySqlQuery("SELECT 1 + 190 / 2 AS solution;") } > SQL PUSH </button>
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')`

**This is the error in the DevTools console:**
[image: Error in DevTools console]

**This is the error in Next.js, when i use `throw Error()`.**
[image: This is the error in Next.js]

Comment: You're making life difficult for yourself by using the `onClick` wrapper provided by React in this way. Write a handler in your component that calls your `MySQLQuery()` function from there.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for the comment. Can you specify "handler"? Do you mean just create a function that calls mySqlQuery()?

Comment: look at the examples on [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: The try `try`/`catch` block _is_ working, the code you have inside the block is erroring and you're seeing the error being caught/thrown.

Comment: Also, [`mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) is a Node.js package, it can't be used on the client-side (browser) where you're attempting to use it. You should move that logic to the backend and/or API route.

Comment: @juliomalves Right, of course. Thank you for the clarification. Would you mind answering that so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the `try` block is erroring, and you're seeing the error being caught/thrown in the `catch` block.

[`mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) is a Node.js package, it can't be used on the client-side in the browser. You have to move the logic to the backend or to an API route, then make a request against that on the client-side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I used [this guide](https://www.simplenextjs.com/posts/next-mysql) to create a solution that worked for me. Very useful, i recommend it you're a beginner like me.